# Update table column on new row insert

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

I am using POSTGRESQL,I have 2 tables, one represents customer (id,name,address,etc...), and the other one I am using as a customer id generator (customer_id). I want to create a function to increase the customer_id number on the second table when a new customer is inserted on the first table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_customer
  AFTER INSERT
  ON customer
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_customer_id();
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Most products have their own versions of triggers and stored procedures.)

Comment: What about sequences, identity columns etc?

Comment: I am using postgresql, the first table is customer(id, address, email, phone1) and the second table is customer_id( id ) The second table stores a fresh unused value for new customer entries, so when a new customer is created it uses this id from customer_id table . So when a new customer entry is inserted I want to increase the id value of customer_id table by 1 so it is ready for use on another row

Comment: Why don't you use a sequence? Much faster and safe for concurrent inserts

Comment: I havent used a sequence before, how can I do this any references?

Comment: I made it using a sequence column for id, worked just fine, for educational purposes only is it possible to create a trigger to make this procedure?

Comment: Use a sequence. What you're trying is a guaranteed to create a duplicate key in a multi-user environment at some point in time. The reason is that until it's committed the update cannot be seen by other sessions. Thus User_A updates this second table but User_B reads it before User_A commits. Both users will generate the same id. That will not happen with a sequence.